# ASP.net MVC2 - Customize Metadata without using Custom Attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dynamic, model

I'm pretty new to MVC, I'm trying to create a model that can be localized, but it doesn't seem like that would be possible given that I have to use a custom property attribute to define displayname and validation properties.

Is there a way to dynamically create the model metadata attributes (DisplayName, UIHint, etc..) as opposed to having to define each one using custom property attributes?  Ideally i'd like to keep my metadata in a table, xml file - something along those lines.

Comment: So far I have found a promising way of doing this using a the ModelMetadataProvider abstract classes.  

There is a good article here on it http://weblogs.asp.net/seanmcalinden/archive/2010/06/11/custom-asp-net-mvc-2-modelmetadataprovider-for-using-custom-view-model-attributes.aspx.